# how i extract From time,To time(appointment time) from html table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am selecting time slot on dragging on time slot cell. After selecting time slot, I enter patient name in textbox and click on select button then patient name goes to selected time slot. The user can select multiple time slot for multilpe patient name and onclick of allot button I have to insert patient name with time slot (From time To time) to database.

I have problem in getting alloted time slot ie.From time and To time in jquery.

```
$("#btnAllot").click(function () {
    //how i get alloted time here.
    $('tr').each(function () {
        $(this).find('td').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('yell')) {
                alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text());

            };
        });
    });
}
```

I have used above but get only minute  not patient name, hour.
[see live jsbin demo here](http://jsbin.com/owarip/edit#preview)
[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yebJ6/)

Comment: Your live demo does not have any code in the click handler for `#btnAllot` so no-one can see what output you are getting. I've tried copying your code above into the handler and it doesn't produce an alert - please amend your live demo so that it produces the output you describe.

Comment: i've not tested your code, but only see, anyway try to loop on the time slot column, $('table tr td:nth-child(2)').each(function(){ and divide the slot if($(this).hasClass('yell')){ and so on...

Comment: Sorry see i have edited my quetion and add code on button allot button also.

Answer (score 1):

You only get minute because you only pick *Time Slot* column value, see [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yebJ6/2/):

```
$("#btnAllot").click(function() {
    $('tr:gt(0)').each(function() {
        if ($(this).has("td[class='yell']")){
            var hour = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
            var slot = $(this).find('td:eq(1)').text();
            var name = $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text();
            var msg = 'Hour: ' + hour + ' Slot: ' + slot + ' Name: ' + name;
            alert(msg);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is giving header text also not like what he wants The user can select multiple time slot for multilpe patient name

Comment: Edited the answer, this is just an example to show that OP can get other column values too using `:eq()`.